# can c++ tcpserver receive unsigned char?

Tags: c++, tcp

Currently I have a c# tcpclient and a c++ tcpserver, but I can only read chars from the stream at the server side thus all the data will be casted to char. Since c++ char is a signed 8-bit integer, but c# client sends byte, which is unsigned 8-bit integer, so all the data >=128 sent from client cannot be received correctly at server side.
Example:

```
        char[] textChars = text.ToCharArray();
        byte[] textBytes = new byte[textChars.Length *2];
        byte low;
        byte high;
        UInt16 current;
        for (int i = 0; i < textChars.Length; i++)
        {
            current = (UInt16)textChars[i];
            high = (byte)(current / 256);
            low = (byte)(current % 256);
            textBytes[i * 2] = high;
            textBytes[i * 2 + 1] = low;
        }

        currentStream.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
        currentStream.Flush();
```

This is at client side, and I print out what I received at server side as a signed int:
if i send a char with its ascii code = 136, which will become 2 bytes:0,136. but at server side, it prints 0, -22.
So is there a way to have c++ stream read unsigned char?
or is there another way to solve this?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can re-cast received chars to byte by (unsigned char)

Answer (score 1):

All you're getting over the TCP connection is raw data, it's how you choose to *interpret* it that decides what it looks like.

Easiest solution is to probably cast it before printing/using with something like:

```
signed char val = -22;               // emulate receipt of signed char.
printf ("%d\n", (unsigned char)val); // cast to change interpretation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is broken.

```
char[] textChars = text.ToCharArray();
....
for (int i = 0; i < textChars.Length; i++)
{
    current = (UInt16)textChars[i];
```

the elements of "textChars" are of type "char". that means they contain a value between 0-255. On the next line, you do:

```
    high = (byte)(current / 256);
```

this can only ever evalute to 0.